# I can not use ssh to connect to the debian sshd

Tags: debian, ssh, filezilla

I have a debian server, in my mac I use filezilla to `ssh` connect to it, but get the below error:

```
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
Error:  Can not connect to server
```

the below is the debian sshd's config:

```
Host *

PasswordAuthentication yes

SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Seems can not use password to connect, why.

---

**EDIT-01**

In my Mac to connect I get permission error:

```
$ ssh root@192.168.64.2
root@192.168.64.2: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Can you connect using Terminal from your Mac? Just in case filezilla is to blame, it'd be nice to check that a normal ssh from Terminal works.

Comment: Please explicitly name the file you're editing on the server, I think perhaps there's a mix-up. The file you're editing should be `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` followed by a `service ssh restart` after modification.

I would also recommend that you reconsider enabling password auth (particularly for root) and would be happy to help with getting that working.

Comment: @gary Why enable password auth for root? That is a potential security risk.

Comment: @panki I'm recommending _against_ enabling password auth for root, which is what OP is attempting to achieve.